# Private embedded shopify app

Tags: javascript, html, sdk, shopify

I'm trying to build Embedded Private App and something I'm missing. As it is instructed [here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/creating-a-private-app), I created App, got API key. Then a very simple page with content:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.init({
      apiKey: 'my-private-api-key',
      shopOrigin: 'https://my-dev-shop.myshopify.com',
      debug: true
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
Private app
</body>
```

And I'll I get by visiting this page is redirect to my shop with screen.

```
The page you're looking for can't be found.
Try a search instead.
```

Redirect URL is

```
https://my-dev-shop.myshopify.com/admin/apps/my-private-api-key/
```

What I am missing? It's my first experience with shopify at all, so maybe I missing all understanding how EASDK works. I tested it from localhost and from my domain with SSL. Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I can tell you a solution if you can tell me the purpose of the app? Are you doing it for a client or you plan to release it in the market?

Answer (score 11):

I would like to pay more attention to **Embedded Apps** and tell more about my experience and problems I met before I managed to create and install it as a private app.

Embedded Apps allows to modify look and feel of admin part of Shopify. Actually there is no special app type called "Embedded Apps" in Shopify. App creator can just enable "Embedded App" SDK when he creates regular "public" app in his Partners account. So if this feature is enabled - the app can use Embedded App SDK in store's admin.

My problem was to realize **how to install Embedded App to the store and how to make it private** i.e available to stores without publishing to App Store. The answer is:

- we need create a regular public app with "Embedded App SDK" enabled
  (using partners account)
- we do not need to publish it to store (so
  no-one excepting us will know about it)
- we need to install it in store's admin.

Last action means that we need to do everything as it is described for regular public Shopify Apps i.e allow the app to access the store using OAuth handshake. The procedure is described [here](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth).

Let me repeat some points:

1. Send request like this `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={api_key}&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`. *Replace `{strings in curly braces}` with appropriate values. Note `{redirect_uri}` must be one of Redirection URL specified in app settings, `{scopes}` should be replaced with one of allowed scopes from [here](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth#scopes) (I used the first scope, it was not important for me, I did not want to modify data, I just wanted t use Embedded App SDK UI methods).*
2. In result it will send you to `example.org/some/redirect/uri?code={authorization_code}&hmac=da9d83c171400a41f8db91a950508985&timestamp=1409617544&state={nonce}&shop={hostname}`
   *(example.org/some/redirect/uri is a redirect_url pointed in first request) and expect that a this query is properly handled on your side.*
3. "Properly handled" means that POST request will be sent to
   `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token` and it will have following fields:

- `client_id` - the API Key for the app
- `client_secret` - the Shared Secret for the app
- `code` - the {authorization_code} came with query.

I did not need any backend stuff so I just created simple html form with all necessary fields and submitted it (`method=POST`, `action=https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token`) and received a json with access token.

After it in admin of the store in Apps section you must see link to added app. After clicking on it here it will try to open load iframe with src equal to Application URL of your app. This URL must point to your app i.e a html where you can do what you want. Normally people want to use SDK methods.
Please note possible http/https issues

Comment: This no longer works due to the deprecation of unpublished apps. Shopify's suggested replacement is custom apps, which do not support embedding (a very irritating choice on Shopify's part).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you set your "App settings" > "Embedded settings" to disabled (standalone app) but use your app as an embedded app. Just set your "Embedded settings" to enabled and your app will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Under private apps there is no this choice.

Comment: You are right, it looks as if you can't use a private app in embedded mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with the same problem and tried different things...

As stated on [this forum post](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/new-embed-your-app-inside-of-shopify-176311#comment-179005) by a "Shopify Employee", it seems to be possible for a private app to be embedded. I can't find how though.

> True private applications do not use OAuth and do not get listed in the Shopify admin, however you can create an App in your partners area, never publish it to the App store and only allow it to be installed on whichever shops you please. These Apps will be listed in the admin and will have full access to the EASDK.

This is what I did :

- create a private app with EASDK enabled (Embedded Settings section on the app's settings page)
- install my code on a HTTPS server
- create a private app key on my shop's settings page

At this point, I could access my shop's products and orders through the PHP API, leading me to believe that my app was installed.

I then copied the code provided on [Shopify's embedded app SDK initialization doc](http://docs.shopify.com/embedded-app-sdk/initialization). I open this page in my browser and am automatically redirected to a 404.
URL oh that page looks like `https://name-of-my-shop.myshopify.com/admin/apps/ID_OF_MY_APP/`

I also tried this (didn't work) :

- generate an "install link" using the PHP API's method [install_url](https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify_api#generating-the-apps-installation-url-for-a-given-store)
- click on that link, showing the message *(Name of my app) has been granted read/write access to your Shopify data.*

Any input from a Shopify guru would be appreciated

NB. It also seems that the API evolves a lot and this might be a temporary issue, but I surely hope it is not and we can solve this !